# Shell script does not recognize alias

Tags: python, zsh, alias, zshrc

I have a file named `run`. These are the contents:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

python
```

To make the file executable, I ran `chmod a+x run`. I typed in `./run` into the terminal. It activates the Python 2.7 shell. The reason this is unexpected is because in my `.zshrc` file I have an alias: `alias python="python3"`. Why does zsh not recognize my alias?

Comment: This is for bash, not zsh, but should help you understand the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Put your alias line before the `python` call

Comment: @Hedy What do you mean by "alias line"?

Comment: `alias python="python3"`

Comment: @Hedy That is in my `.zshrc` file which is located at `~/.zshrc`. `run` is located at `~/Documents/PythonGame/run`

Comment: I know that, I just thought that putting the alias into the script (as well as in zshrc if you like) then run `python` might work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable alias processing. Do in your script a

```
setopt aliases
```

before defining your alias.

Comment: It doesn't work? I tried putting it in both `run` **and** `~/.zshrc` and even restarted the shell, but it still doesn't work. The only thing that has worked so far is putting the alias in `run` as @Hedy suggested.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 : `.zshrc` doesn't matter in this context. It is not processed by your script anyway. **Inside** `run`, you have to do `setopt aliases; alias python="python3"`, as I explained in my answer (_do it **in** your script, **before** defining your alias_)